# Calculate percent of roads (by length) where condition is >=15

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-12c, aggregate

I have a road condition table:

```
CONDITION       LENGTH
    2              5
    4             10
    6             15
    8             20
   10             25
   12             30
   14             35
   16             40
   18             45
   20             50
```

Roads that are at a condition of **15 or greater** ( a.k.a. `15_OG`) are considered to be in a **good** condition.

I want to calculate the percentage of roads (by length) that are at a **good condition**.

```
LENGTH_15_OG    TOTAL_LENGTH    PERCENT_15_OG
     135             275            49.09%
```

---

How can I do this calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little modification to save 1 table access:

```
select
  length_15_og, total_length,
  round(length_15_og/total_length*100, 2) as percent_15_og
from
(
  select
    sum(case when condition >= 15 then length end) as length_15_og,
    sum(length) as total_length
  from
    road_condition
);
```

Answer (score 3):

There will be other solutions - but how about ...

```
select 
  length_15_og
, total_length
, round( length_15_og / total_length * 100, 2 ) as percent_15_og
from (
  select 
    ( select sum( length ) from road_condition where condition >= 15 ) as length_15_og
  , ( select sum( length ) from road_condition ) as total_length
  from dual
) ;

-- result
LENGTH_15_OG  TOTAL_LENGTH  PERCENT_15_OG  
135           275           49.09
```

[Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bb4561db6e11d9f5e62fcf5132218a73)

Answer (score 2):

A non-nested solution making use of case statements:

```
select
  sum(case when CONDITION >= 15 then LENGTH else 0 end) as LENGTH_15_OG,
  sum(LENGTH) as TOTAL_LENGTH,
  100 * sum(case when CONDITION >= 15 then 1.0*LENGTH else 0 end) / sum(LENGTH) as PERCENT_15_OG
from ROADS
```